# Does Gatsby GraphQL Need Surrounding Parentheses?

Tags: gatsby, graphql-js

I'm new to Gatsby, especially the **interesting** syntax choices (only use template literals for strings, don't include ending semicolons).

My question is: **do you need parentheses surrounding graphql queries**? The documentation doesn't really explain the syntax around using graphql, and the tutorials have queries with and without surrounding parentheses.

[Gatsby tutorial - uses surrounding parentheses](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/#creating-pages)

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  ...
  const result = await graphql(`     <--- parentheses here
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))
}
```

[Gatsby tutorial - no surrounding parentheses](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-four/#use-a-page-query)

```
export const query = graphql`     <--- no parentheses here
  query {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Is it because of the `await` on the first example, or am I not understanding something else? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `gatsby-node.js` file you need to use a regular old function, namely `graphql()`.

In React land/components you can use [tagged templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as shown in your second example. This is because Gatsby among other things then uses Babel to extract that query and runs it.